# Request["__EVENTTARGET"] call killing page lifecycle

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms, wizard

This one is absolutely bizzare. Alarm bells are probably ringing as to why I am inspecting this property, and probably indicates to you that I am trying to do something "out of step" or circumventing the ASP.NET Page LifeCycle's prescribed event management.

I am using a Wizard in a quite a nested hierarchy and within an update panel. Wizards, if you dont already know, require initialisation/loading of all of the Wizard step  controls upfront.

I am trying to do something a bit quirky (not exactly super quirky) in that I am trying to dynamically load  Wizards based on a user choice. Now this works, but has required a bit of shoe horning.

Anyway, the situation arises where retrieving user input to see what wizard they would like to use, means that the wizard are 'inited' "before" i can get at the choice they have made (by way of drop down or button)  I look it up earlier than the prescribed framework intends the values to be looked up to do some necessary initialisation in the page init event (as mentioned before, a requirement for using Wizards and the Wizard steps they comprise of).

Anyway I have swapped this from just a drop down, to a drop down and a button and need to see which one is clicked.  The call to Request["__EVENTTARGET"] makes the rest of the page processing, not work. I suppose I  should roll my own DynamicWizard control?

Comment: Further investigation has found that this call Page.FindControl(Request["__EVENTTARGET"]) appears to be right at the root of the problems.

Comment: This sounds familiar, I think I've run into this problem before. I was trying to traverse the control hierarchy OnInit, and my page skipped the authentication phase somehow. 
I'm home now, but if this question is still around when I'm back at work tomorrow, I will dig up what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` equal to `null`? That may be because regular buttons don't populate the `__EVENTTARGET` hidden field (they don't have to). You can change that by setting [`UseSubmitBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx) to false for the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="SelectWizard" runat="server" 
  Text="Select" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```